# design view issue - android

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-studio

I am using `intelliJ` and opening a new customized `master/details` template. The problem is that the `design view` is not working. I get this message :

```
Rendering Problems : 

the following classes could not be found

-include (fix build path)
```

When I click on `fix build path` I get a bunch of file that have compiling problem `src/debug/aidl`, `src/debug/assets`, `src/main/`... So where do I get the right packages to install ?

Comment: Following this and similar problems, I moved back to Eclipse. Android Studio is far from ready for production.